# If an Android phone is rebooted, will services that were previously scheduled to be created still be created?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

For example, I create a Service and using the onStartCommand method I return START_REDELIVER_INTENT. This means that if the service didn't finish handling the Intent, then the Service will be scheduled to be restarted with that same intent until that intent is completely handled. If this happens, but the phone is rebooted before the phone has a chance to restart that service, will the same intent be delivered to the service the next time the service is started (after the phone has rebooted, or the next time the user runs the application that created the service)? Or will that intent disappear and never be handled by that service?

EDIT: I was able to test it and the answer is that the intent disappears and does not get handled by the service. One more thing I noticed while testing is that if an application is FORCE STOPPED by the user, then any Intents that were not handled will never be handled by the service, whether or not the phone goes through a reboot. Even though the service can be restarted by manually opening the app again, the previously unhandled Intents will still not be handled, only new intents will be handled after the app is manually started.

Comment: I would expect that the intent disappears. It should be pretty easy to test this though.

Comment: It is not possible AFAIK to manually kill a service and schedule it to be restarted (these are automatic things that happen on their own in the Android system), so how would it be possible to test something like this?

Comment: Based on the documentation for START_REDELIVER_INTENT, it seemed to me that rebooting the phone while processing the intent would trigger the redelivery if they persisted through reboot. Since the service didn't signal that the service completed processing the intent, it would be redelivered if possible? Also, I think crashing the service might trigger the redeliver if you're looking for a way to test it (I remember running into something similar while tracking down a bug).

Comment: Yes crashing would trigger the redelivery, however since the phone has enough memory, it will restart the service right away, I won't have time to reboot the phone which is necessary to test this.

Comment: @Mohsin : There is a difference between manually stopping an app and rebooting a device. If a user goes to Settings -> Apps and uses Force Stop then no part of that app will ever run again until the user manually starts it again (using the app launcher for example). If the phone is rebooted without the user explicitly Force Stopping the app beforehand then app components will be allowed to restart without user intervention. In that case, it would be easy to test to see if the original `Intent`` is persisted and redelivered.